# How can I format the output with System.out?

Tags: java, java-io, system.out

I am creating a Premier League football table in my spare time and I have come across a problem. While the program runs I want it to be perfect and output in the format I want it to, the problem is:

- You enter the the Input (" HomeTeam : AwayTeam : HomeScore : AwayScore ") as follows
- When you are done with the list you enter "quit" to stop the program
- My issue is that the scores come out like this 
  (" HomeTeam | AwayTeam | HomeScore | AwayScore ")
- I intend it to print like this (" HomeTeam [HomeScore] | AwayTeam [AwayScore] ")

I have tried many variations of System.out.printlns to no avail, even trying to make several Boolean conditions that will output the input in the way I want it too. I am truly at a loss and it is frustrating - I hope that someone can give me tips the code is attached

Edited for loop;

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) { // A loop
    String[] words = product_list[i].split(":"); 
    System.out.println(words[0].trim() + "[" + words[2].trim() + "]" + " | " + words[1].trim() + "[" + words[3].trim()) + "]";
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. You should paste the actual code into the question and not a image of the code, otherwise people can't help you. Use the [edit] button to correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public void outputScore(String input) {

    String[] words = input.trim().split("\\s+");

    String satisfied = sc.nextLine();

    if (satisfied.equals("quit")) {
        System.out.println(words[0] + " [" + words[4] + "] | " + words[2] + " [" + words[6] + "]");
    }
}
```

This is what the method should look like when you call it:

```
outputScore(sc.nextLine());
```

Here is the code to your edited question:

```
String [] product_list = new String [100];
int counter = 0;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input as follows:");
System.out.println("Home team : Away team : Home score : Away score");

String line = null;

while (!(line = scanner.nextLine()).equals("")) {

    if (line.equals("quit")) {
           break;
    } else {
        product_list[counter] = line;

        System.out.println("Home team : Away team : Home score : Away score");
    }

    counter++;  
}

for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    String[] words = product_list[i].split(":");
    System.out.println(words[0].trim() + " : " + words[2].trim() + " | " + words[1].trim() + " : " + words[3].trim());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I'm new to java is it ok if you help me understand what is going on and where I should place this code?

I am very grateful for your help I really appreciate it

Comment: No problem, that's why I am here :). About the code, I created an instance of a Scanner class, which scans user input. I stored the input (names of teams and their score) into a String. I split the String into separate words and put them into an Array. Then I stored next user input into a String, and asked if the input is "quit". If it is so, the console outputs names of the teams and scores you typed in at the beginning, in the format you want. Hope this helps. If anything is unclear, feel free to ask me for further information.

Comment: About where to put this piece of code: I don't have any source code of your program, so I can't give you an accurate answer. But you can do something like this: I will edit the code above so you can use it in your program.

Comment: Hi, I understand what the code does and I've been trying for some time now to implement it into my code - sorry to bother you but could I ask for your help once again ^^

I will attach my code

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, I feel guilty asking but could you once again walk me through the code - I'm trying to learn and not just copy ^^

Comment: I have just copied your code, and replaced your for loop at the end with working one. I have created `for` loop that repeats as many times as many Strings your `product_list` contain. Then, I split the String into words, by ":" symbol - so it basically splits your input `Home team : Away team : Home score : Away score` into 4 Strings, and I have just printed them with `System.out.println()` in the order you want - `Home team : Home score | Away team : Away score`.

Comment: Ok the code works well however I changed it so the score would be inside square brackets like so "[2]" and I have had success in the home score however I cannot close the away score without receiving an error.

The output looks like this "Leeds [2] | Liverpool [5"

I will put the for loop I edited in the main section at the top

Comment: Also in the "while (!(line = scanner.nextLine()).equals(""))" code could you tell me why the "!" is significant - I took it out and the whole program didn't work I'm curious

Comment: The Away Score doesn't work because you have to close `System.out.println();` with a bracket ")". You did this - `System.out.println(;`. About the exclamation mark, the statement in the `while` loop is a boolean, return true only if the next line of the scanner is equal to "" - empty line. If I put an exclamation mark before a boolean, it reverses the boolean. So the code in the loop will process only if the the next line in the scanner is "not" empty, by not, I mean the exclamation mark.

Comment: Everything in the brackets in `System.out.println();` will print to the console. You did this - `System.out.println(some stuff) + some stuff`;. It should be only `System.out.println(some stuff);`. The `+ "]"` should be inside the brackets.